# pywinauto how to find more properties (control_identifiers)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, automation, pywinauto

im trying to do gui automation windows with pywinauto, python(pycharm) on some software

i connect to software with the title and (backend="uia") first window is login i input username & password and click log in everything works fine

but after the login the software open new window with many option (tabs, treeMenu, etc) i print all the identifiers (print_control_identifiers() - only for the first top window)

but its not find all for the other tabs / menus / windows (even not half of the software elements)
for example when i do right click on something in the treeMenu (to open right click menu)

**i cant find the identifiers (properties) to control the element**
**also when i move tabs in the software and open new window when i click on something**

images for example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXJmn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di0bF.png)

how can i find every time all the elements in other tabs / window / menu / context menu.
Basically all the elements in the software?

Comment: Maybe it's worth using `Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Main Window").dump_tree()`? Some apps have few processes with different subwindows in each one.

Comment: Hi @VasilyRyabov thank you for the answer i got it 
maybe you can help with this problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68893384/pywinauto-control-connect-to-window-like-popup

Answer (score 0):

you can use Spy++ tool from Microsoft's visual studio  [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide additional information on how OP can solve their problem with your suggestion. Link-only answers are rarely useful.