# Pywinauto control / connect to window like popup

Tags: python, user-interface, automation, automated-tests, pywinauto

Im try to do some gui automation with pywinauto on software i succeeded to open the software then do some thing like connect to top window and click on elements and type_keys on edit fields (input) and login

but there is a problem when i click on some element new window was opening but i cant do actions on the window - no title to connect i cant find the window i was try with top window
but its now working

its like popup window that make some installation and i cant control the window or any elements on the window

**see on image example**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CeeC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hY65.png)

EDIT 1:
i try to connect with top_window() - not working
and i try to create new connection to the top window but i dont have any title

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know if the new window is top level or child of main window. You can use `Inspect.exe` from Windows SDK to view the elements hierarchy or `print([w.window_text() for w in Desktop(backend="uia").windows()])` to print all top level window titles.